# when preprocessor directives are called by a function, the output differs. why?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

This question was asked in an interview and i completely had no idea about how the output differs. Following is the question

```
#define a 10
void foo();
int main()
{
   printf("%d..",a);
   foo();
   printf("%d",a);
}
void foo()
{
   #undef a
   #define a 50
}
```

this gives me 10..10 as output while.,

```
#define a 10
void foo()
{
   #undef a
   #define a 50
}
int main()
{
   printf("%d..",a);
   foo();
   printf("%d",a);
}
```

this gives me 50..50 as the output.
please explain. thank you

Comment: You cant *call* a preprocessor directive. They are macros, *expanded* before compilation even begins (hence the name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocessor is run before the code is compiled in the order in which preprocessor directives appear in the file and not in the order of functions defined in the file.

Comment: Of course @SouravGhosh

Answer (score 2):

This happens because, preprocessing substitution happens even before the actual compilation, it does not take place in run-time.

The value (or definition) of a `#define` directive is valid as per the written code syntax, not as per the calling convention.

So, in the first case

```
#define a 10                 // a is defined here
void foo();
int main()
{
   printf("%d..",a);         // a == 10, substitution happens
   foo();                    //nothing useful here
   printf("%d",a);           // a == 10, substitution happens
}
void foo()
{
   #undef a                 // a vanished
   #define a 50             // a is redefined as 50
}                           // a will be substituted to 50 hereon, is used
```

whereas, in second case

```
#define a 10               // a is defined here
void foo()
{
   #undef a                // a vanished
   #define a 50            // a is redefined as 50
}                          // a will be substituted to 50 hereon, is used
int main()
{
   printf("%d..",a);      // a == 50, substitution happens
   foo();                  // nothing useful here
   printf("%d",a);        // a == 50, substitution happens
}
```